# What does the de- prefix in dereference mean? Is there a linguistic explanation for it?

Tags: c, dereference

I learned that `*` is the value-at operator and `&` the address-of operator. Formally known as dereferencing and referencing. Whenever I talk to someone I trip over the word dereferencing, because it reminds me of the word referencing and then I get confused. I know from how I learn that if I know what the de- prefix of dereference means I won't have this problem anymore.

In the same manner I learned what ante means in poker or what an antagonist and agonist is in neuroscience (and theater w.r.t. antagonist).

Another reason I trip up is because from my (limited) understanding the de- prefix in dereference seems to imply a deletion of a reference, which is not the case.

So what does de- mean? Is there a linguistic explanation or is it an ad-hoc prefix with no meaning other than differentiating from reference?

Possible duplicates: [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4955198/what-does-dereferencing-a-pointer-mean) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14224831/meaning-of-referencing-and-dereferencing?rq=1) but I'm not asking for the definition of dereferencing. I'm asking what the prefix means in the context of the word (edit: and also in the technical context, I'm not interested in dereferencing a real book, whatever that means).

Comment: de is latin for un.  de is to dereference as un is to undo.    similar to a fx/dx(f'(x))

Comment: Maybe you should ask on 'EL&U' ([English Language & Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/))?

Comment: There was this chap from Normandy that invaded. We had a bit of a tiff in Hastings. He got involved in British politics and he spoke French. Sort of introduced French into English (beef, pork, mutton etc). "De" being a bit of this. It means of.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: in all seriousness, I can't ask it on English language forms, because they don't know the subtle differences between dereferencing a pointer and dereferencing something else. Perhaps I didn't put it clearly enough in the description but I was asking it in the context of the word but also in the context of dereferencing a pointer. Hence an English speaking programmer would give a more precise answer than someone who doesn't program but speaks English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not a linguist but here goes. First, from google:

> de- a prefix occurring in loanwords from Latin ( decide); also used to indicate privation, removal, and separation ( dehumidify), negation ( demerit; derange), descent ( degrade; deduce), reversal ( detract), intensity ( decompound).

The `de-` prefix here means to negate what follows. Similar to an `un-` prefix (do / undo). So when we use the `&` operator, we take a reference. When we use the `*` operator, we `de-`reference. We undo the reference operator to get the variable again.

`*(&foo)` == `foo`: `de(reference(foo))`

Comment: Perfect answer exactly what I needed, thanks :) Undoing the reference while going to it sticks into my mind. I didn't associate de- with un- from undo.

Comment: So the `&*` operator combo could be described as "undereferencing"

Comment: Question: is &(*(int *)0) segfault or 0, or UB