# C - What does *(long *)(host->h_addr); do?

Tags: c, casting

I found the following code in [this](https://aticleworld.com/ssl-server-client-using-openssl-in-c/) example:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(long *)(host->h_addr);
```

`h_addr` is is a `char` pointer  and `host` is a pointer to a struct of type `hostent`. `addr` is a struct of type `sockaddr_in` and `sin_addr` is a struct of type `in_addr`. `s_addr` is a `uint32`.

Most of this information can be found here: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/ip.7.html

I'm pretty sure `(long)` casts the char to a long, but I don't know what the extra asterisks do, especially because `s_addr` is not a pointer.

Can someone explain what is happening here?

Comment: See [this SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14224831/416574) post about referencing and dereferencing. The cast is making it a long pointer and then the initial asterisk is dereferencing the long pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`(long *)(host->h_addr)` means to interpret `host->h_addr` as a pointer to a `long`. This is not very portable, but presumably a `long` is 32 bits long on the system this was written for.

The additional star in `*(...)` dereferences what is now a `long` for assignment. This effectively copies all four bytes of the original `char` array into the single `long` value `addr.sin_addr.s_addr`. Compare to `(long)(*host->h_addr)`, which would only copy the first `char` element.

This technique is extremely unportable. It assumes both the size and endianness of the `long` type. You might be tempted to take a hint from the fact that `s_addr` is a `uint32` and do:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = *(uint32_t *)(host->h_addr);
```

This is not really any better because the endianness is still undermined. Also,`uint32_t` is guaranteed to hold *at least* 32 bits. It can be any larger number of bits, which would invoke undefined behavior when you tried to read unallocated memory with the copy (imagine copying your 32 bits of `char` data as a 64-bit integer).

There are two options going forward:

If your `char` array is already in the correct byte order (i.e., you don't care if `h_addr[0]` represents the highest or lowest byte of a local `uint32_t`), use `memcpy`:

```
memcpy(&(addr.sin_addr.s_addr), host->h_addr, 4);
```

This is likely to be the approach you need. If, on the other hand you want `h_addr[0]` to always end up in the highest byte, you need to respect the endianness of your system:

```
addr.sin_addr.s_addr = (host->h_addr[0] << 24) + (host->h_addr[1] << 16) + (host->h_addr[2] << 8) + (host->h_addr[3]);
```

There probably need to be some casts to `uint32_t` along the way there.

Comment: I know this is outside of the scope of the original question - so feel free to not answer - but if this technique is not portable, then what is a better method of doing this?

Comment: @Roymunson. Done

Comment: @Roymunson: `memcpy` is portable... But a better idea is to use the modern `getaddrinfo` instead of the legacy `gethostbyname`. The modern interface avoids this sort of nonsense completely and will deal with future protocols (e.g. IPv6) automatically

Comment: This answer is now incorrect... The `h_addr` field is already in network byte order, which is also what the `s_addr` field needs. Your code will break on little-endian systems (e.g. x86). A simple `memcpy` is what you want and is perfectly portable.

Comment: @Nemo. Will fix

Comment: Suggest using `htonl` macro instead of the shifts

Comment: One slight correction: You say "`uint32_t` is guaranteed to hold at least 32 bits", but it is in fact guaranteed to hold _exactly_ 32-bits. (There are `uint_least32_t` and `uint_fast32_t` for the smallest and "fastest" integer types with at least 32-bits, respectively, but `uint32_t` is fixed width.)

Comment: @Arkku. This just started as a 2 sentence blurb about dereferencing pointers. Now I've learned at least three new things. I appreciate the comments here very much.

Answer (score 0):

The way I'd read this is "addr.sin_addr.s_addr equals object of cast to `long` pointer of host->h_addr", or more briefly, "addr.sin_addr.s_addr equals the `long` pointed to by host->h_addr". `host->h_addr` is presumably a pointer to something other than `long` - here this address is treated as a pointer-to-long and the long it's pointed to is assigned to `addr.sin_addr.s_addr`.

HTH.

Comment: Do you know why `h_addr` was cast to long pointer, which was then deferenced, instead of just directly casting to a long?

Comment: Because `h_addr` is presumably a pointer, and what's wanted is what the pointer `h_addr` points to. `h_addr` is probably a pointer-to-something-other-than-long (perhaps `void *`?), and to get the `long` at the address pointed to by `h_addr`, `h_addr` must be cast to `long *` and then dereferenced.