# Working on a c homework assignment and getting errors I do not understand

Tags: c

I am making a `typedef` to a structure for a "person" The person has a `name, ssn` and `yearOfBirth`. I am getting errors I do not understand with my for loops.

```
[Error] cannot convert 'person_t' to 'person_t*' for argument '1' to 
'void getOnePerson(person_t*)'
```

This is the first file:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "structures.h"
void getOnePerson(person_t *p)
{
    printf("Enter full name: ");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", p -> name);

    printf("Enter ssn: ");
    scanf("%99[^\n]", p -> ssn);

    printf("Enter year of birth: ");
    scanf("%d", &p -> yearOfBirth);
}
void printOnePerson(person_t p)
{
    printf("%s:", p.name);
    printf("%s:", p.ssn);
    printf("%s\n", p.yearOfBirth);

}
void getPeople(person_t p[], int numOfPeople)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    {
        getOnePerson(p[i]);
    }
}
void printPeople(person_t p[], int numOfPeople)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    {
        printOnePerson(p[i]);
    }
}
```

This is my structure file:

```
#define NAME_SIZE 80
#define SSN_SIZE 13
#define NUM_PEOPLE 10
typedef struct 
{
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char ssn[SSN_SIZE];
    int yearOfBirth;
} person_t;
```

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Why do you tag `c++` on a `c` question?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: There are other problems, too. For example, `NAME_SIZE` is undefined. Compile with `-Wall`. For this specific error, the message says what's wrong: You are passing a `person_t` to a function that accepts a `person_t*`.

Comment: Anybody teaching students that code and calling it C++ deserves a pie in the face. Dont 'add' code to the question in the comments - not helpful. Edit the question so that it includes any extra information that was initially missing..

Comment: `getOnePerson(p[i]);` -> `getOnePerson(&p[i]);`

Comment: You fail to ***validate*** the return of `scanf`. You must check the return Every Time, or you are tempting *Undefined Behavior*. You also must change `"%99[^\n]"` to `" %99[^\n]"` because neither `"%c"` or `"%[...]"` consume leading whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it seems to be pointers and references task. You may need to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4996142/7701667) to understand them. In other words,  cannot convert `person_t` to `person_t*` means you are trying to use your object person instead of reference to that specific person. `*` means reference, so you need to pass an address to it using `&`. Im not best explainer, check out the link instead and all answers, not only accepted one.

Code seems quite messy, I tried to fix it to compilable code, although I dont have C compiler (you may need to edit/fix according to your homework details):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define NAME_SIZE 80
#define SSN_SIZE 13
#define NUM_PEOPLE 10

typedef struct 
{
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char ssn[SSN_SIZE];
    int yearOfBirth;
} person_t;

int main()
{
   person_t people[NUM_PEOPLE];
   printf("Get people\n");
   getPeople(&people, 3);

   printf("\nPrint people\n");
   printPeople(people, 3);
   return 0;
}

void getOnePerson(person_t *person)
{
  printf("Enter full name: ");
  scanf("%s", person -> name);
  printf("\nEnter ssn: ");
  scanf("%s", person -> ssn);
  printf("\nEnter year of birth: ");
  scanf("%s", person -> yearOfBirth);
}

void printOnePerson(person_t p)
{
   printf("%s:%s:%d\n", p.name, p.ssn, p.yearOfBirth);
}

void getPeople(person_t *person[], int num)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<num; i++)
   { 
      getOnePerson(&person[i]);
   }
}

void printPeople(person_t person[], int num)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<num; i++)
   {
      printOnePerson(person[i]);
   }
}
```

So, briefly, your `getPeople(person_t *person[], int num)` function's first parameter is `person_t *person[]`, therefore you need to pass a `&people`. Same as  `getOnePerson(person_t *person)` parameter `person_t *person` means you need to pass address to a single person object `&person[i]`. The meaning behind them that using references, you can edit the values in these objects directly in the function. While `printPeople(person_t person[], int num)` and `printOnePerson(person_t p)` are used for reading (not editing) thereby you can pass values themselves.

Answer (score 0):

You have such a large number of small problems, it is difficult to know where to begin. First a nit, you never include spaces around `"->"` when referencing a structure member. Use `p->name`, not `p -> name`. Continuing...

You fail to ***validate*** the return of `scanf`. You must check the return Every Time, or you are tempting *Undefined Behavior*. You also must change `"%99[^\n]"` to `" %79[^\n]"` because neither `"%c"` or `"%[...]"` consume leading whitespace. Failing to add the `" "` before `%12[^\n]` would make it impossible to read `p->ssn` and lead to a *matching failure* reading `p->yearOfBirth`.

**Note** the change from `99` to `79`. You `#define NAME_SIZE 80` and declare `char name[NAME_SIZE];`, what do you think you are doing using a *field-width* modifier of `99` when at most `79` characters can be stored in `name`? (You have the same problem with `#define SSN_SIZE 13`). You use the *field-width* modifier with `scanf` to *protect your array bounds*. Setting the *field-width modifier greater than your array size (`-1`) removes the protection it should provide altogether.

Your failure to check the return of `scanf` and handle the three cases of return necessary will lead to *Undefined Behavior* if the user accidentally makes a single error in input. Failure to check the return of `scanf` is one of the most common pitfall new C programmer fall into. It is mandatory for every user input. Otherwise, you can have no confidence your code is actually processing valid data.

`scanf` can be used, if used correctly. This means **you** are responsible for checking the **return** of `scanf` *every time*. You must handle *three conditions*

1. `(return == EOF)` the user canceled input by generating a manual `EOF` by pressing <kbd>Ctrl+d</kbd> (or on windows <kbd>Ctrl+z</kbd>, but see [CTRL+Z does not generate EOF in Windows 10 (early versions)](http://proc-x.com/2017/06/ctrlz-does-not-generate-eof-in-windows-10/));
2. `(return < expected No. of conversions)` a *matching* or *input* failure occurred. For a *matching* failure you must account for every character left in your input buffer. (scan forward in the input buffer reading and discarding characters until a `'\n'` or `EOF` is found); and finally
3. `(return == expected No. of conversions)` indicating a successful read -- it is then up to you to check whether the input meets any additional criteria (e.g. positive integer, positive floating-point, within a needed range, etc..).

A short function implementation to empty all remaining characters in `stdin` in the event of *matching failure* could be as simple as:

```
void empty_stdin (void)
{
    int c = getchar();

    while (c != '\n' && c != EOF)
        c = getchar();
}
```

(implementing in your code is left as an exercise for you)

Further, using type `void` as the return of an input function makes no sense. You must choose your return to provide the return of required information **AND** provide an indication of whether the input succeeded or failed. Using `void` for `getOnePerson()` means you have no way of knowing whether you received all valid input, or just received `name`, but not `ssn`, or if the user simply generated a manual `EOF` canceling input at each prompt. A simple integer return is all you need (e.g. `return 0;` on failure or `return 1;` only after all 3-inputs are validated) You could do something like:

```
int getOnePerson (person_t *p)
{
    int rtn;    /* scanf return */
    /* validate each input for all 3 cases */
    fputs ("\nEnter full name: ", stdout);   /* no need for printf, no conversion */
    if ((rtn = scanf (" %79[^\n]", p->name)) != 1) {
        if (rtn == EOF)
            puts ("(input complete)");
        else
            fputs ("error: invalid format 'p->name'.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    /* validate each input for all 3 cases */
    fputs ("Enter ssn: ", stdout);          /* ditto */
    if ((rtn = scanf (" %12[^\n]", p->ssn)) != 1) { /*   "   */
        if (rtn != EOF)
            fputs ("error: invalid format 'p->ssn'.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }
    /* validate each input for all 3 cases */
    fputs ("Enter year of birth: ", stdout);
    if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &p->yearOfBirth)) != 1) {
        if (rtn != EOF)
            fputs ("error: invalid format 'p->yearOfBirth'.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;    /* indicates all 3 input successfully received */
}
```

(**note:** input is complete when `EOF` is encountered, either manually generated by the user or encountered in the input stream)

`void` is also meaningless as a return for `getPeople()`. You can't use a `for` loop and just assume all inputs were successful, instead, you need to take input only while input is available, while protecting your array bounds, and then return the number of input actually received (which may be less than `NUM_PEOPLE`). Further, choose your type properly. For counters, `size_t` is the proper type (you can't have a negative number of persons), e.g.

```
size_t getPeople (person_t *p, size_t numOfPeople)
{
    // for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    // {
    //     getOnePerson(p[i]);
    // }

    size_t n = 0;

    while (n < numOfPeople && getOnePerson (&p[n]))
        n++;

    return n;
}
```

When you pass an array as a parameter to a function, the array is converted to *a pointer* to the first element. So when you do `sizeof(p)` within a function -- that is not what you want and does not provide the number of elements in the array referenced by `p` -- what it does provide is `sizeof(a_pointer)`, which is fixed by your compiler (e.g. 8-bytes on x86_64, 4-bytes on x86). You pass `numOfPeople` -- use it, e.g.

```
void printPeople (person_t *p, size_t numOfPeople)
{
    puts ("\nStored People\n");

    // for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numOfPeople; i++)
    {
        printOnePerson(p[i]);
    }
}
```

You will also want to fix `printf("%s\n", p.yearOfBirth);` (`yearOfBirth` is not a string...)

Your header is fine, but it is missing something. Always include header guards around the content of your header files to prevent multiple inclusions of the file, e.g.

```
#ifndef mystructures_h
#define mystructures_h  1
...
/* your header content */
...
#endif
```

(**note:** the `1` isn't required, but if you are defining a constant, it is never a bad idea to give it an affirmative value of your choosing)

There are probably more that were corrected, but those were the major points. Putting it altogether, you could do:

**structures.h**

```
#ifndef mystructures_h
#define mystructures_h  1

#include <stdio.h>

#define NAME_SIZE 80
#define SSN_SIZE 13
#define NUM_PEOPLE 10

typedef struct  {
    char name[NAME_SIZE];
    char ssn[SSN_SIZE];
    int yearOfBirth;
} person_t;

size_t getPeople (person_t *p, size_t numOfPeople);
void printPeople (person_t *p, size_t numOfPeople);


#endif
```

(can you figure out why `#include <stdio.h>` was moved from `structures.c` into `structures.h`? do you know why the function prototypes for `getPeople()` and `printPeople()` are required in the header and not the rest?)

**structures.c**

```
#include "structures.h"

int getOnePerson (person_t *p)
{
    int rtn;    /* scanf return */

    fputs ("\nEnter full name: ", stdout);
    if ((rtn = scanf (" %79[^\n]", p->name)) != 1) {
        if (rtn == EOF)
            puts ("(input complete)");
        else
            fputs ("error: invalid format 'p->name'.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    fputs ("Enter ssn: ", stdout);          /* ditto */
    if ((rtn = scanf (" %12[^\n]", p->ssn)) != 1) { /*   "   */
        if (rtn != EOF)
            fputs ("error: invalid format 'p->ssn'.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    fputs ("Enter year of birth: ", stdout);
    if ((rtn = scanf ("%d", &p->yearOfBirth)) != 1) {
        if (rtn != EOF)
            fputs ("error: invalid format 'p->yearOfBirth'.\n", stderr);
        return 0;
    }

    return 1;
}

size_t getPeople (person_t *p, size_t numOfPeople)
{
    // for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    // {
    //     getOnePerson(p[i]);
    // }

    size_t n = 0;

    while (n < numOfPeople && getOnePerson (&p[n]))
        n++;

    return n;
}

void printOnePerson (person_t p)
{
    printf("%s:", p.name);
    printf("%s:", p.ssn);
    // printf("%s\n", p.yearOfBirth);
    printf("%d\n", p.yearOfBirth);
}

void printPeople (person_t *p, size_t numOfPeople)
{
    puts ("\nStored People\n");

    // for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(p); i++)
    for (size_t i = 0; i < numOfPeople; i++)
    {
        printOnePerson(p[i]);
    }
}
```

**A short test program `peopletest.c`**

```
#include "structures.h"

int main (void) {

    person_t people[NUM_PEOPLE] = {{ .name = "" }};
    size_t npeople = getPeople (people, NUM_PEOPLE);

    printPeople (people, npeople);
}
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/peopletest

Enter full name: Person A. One
Enter ssn: 123456789
Enter year of birth: 2001

Enter full name: Person B. Two
Enter ssn: 234567890
Enter year of birth: 2002

Enter full name: Person C. Three
Enter ssn: 345678901
Enter year of birth: 2003

Enter full name: (input complete)

Stored People

Person A. One:123456789:2001
Person B. Two:234567890:2002
Person C. Three:345678901:2003
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.